# Masking user identity in a Q&A forum or allowing users to ask anonymously in a social intranet

Tags: identity, masking

we are going to launch Jive-social intranet(jive software.com) in our company. We would like to give option to allow users to ask question anonymously (after loggin in). Kindly advise how we could do that from admin console.